# Error: cannot access zzbej class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found

Tags: java, android, xml

I created an android project. while I'm running or building apk it will show an error. How to solve this problem? all is well. while I'm syncing the project it will work fine. But, when I'm trying to run this on emulator or building APK it's showing this below error.

Error

> error: cannot access zzbej class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found

[image: error]

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }//for android O
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        resValue 'string', 'package_name', applicationId
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 54
        versionName "1.5.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        renderscriptTargetApi 26
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }//this until  Google release a fix .bottomsheet super
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        dexInProcess = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }


    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def supportLibsVer = "26.+"
    def googlePlayServicesVer = "11.6.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibsVer"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$googlePlayServicesVer"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$googlePlayServicesVer"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googlePlayServicesVer"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.16@aar'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.5.2'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
    implementation 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1-native'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3' // required for link preview
    implementation 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'

}
```

Project Gradle
build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can you help me to solve this problem?